# Что такое "юз"?

Tags: этимология

Когда некий предмет, например, машину (или моего кота))) заносит на поворотах, и этот предмет несется уже по инерции, особенно, если покрытие дороги скользкое, говорят, что его несет юзом.
А что это вообще за слово? Сразу напоминает английское слово "use" - использовать и производные от него на компьютерном жаргоне "юзать", "юзер". Но это, вроде как, не то. Или "юз" - все-таки русское слово?

Answer (score 1):

Юз - проскальзывание по поверхности, не связанное с качением (вращением колёс). Произошло от наречия "юзом" из жаргона грузчиков (альтернатива - "катом"). Означает перемещение груза волоком - не переворачивая его при движении. С 'use' не связано: имевшееся ранее слово "юз" относили к телетайпному аппарату (изобретатель Hughes).

Comment: Каким образом use может быть связано с Hughes??? там и произношение-то разное...

Comment: Так в словаре Ушакова для слова "юз". Правила транскрипции собств. имён с английского со временем менялись. Там же о происхождении наречия "юзом".

Answer (score 1):

юза юза́ церк. форма, соответствующая у́за II (см.). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Comment: Соглачен полностью.

Comment: Значение слова "узы": оковы, путы. О смысловой связи с употреблением слова "юз" м.р. где-нибудь упоминается?

Answer (score 0):

В Нац. корпусе, слово «юзом» (двигаться) упоминается начиная с середины 20 века.

«На страх рабам и музам
Марс был солдатом, 
Воюя их то юзом, 
То в лёт, то катом.»
[Г.Н. Оболдуев. «Удел твой, человек...» [Я видел, 9] (1941-1952)]

«…автомобиль становился поперек дороги и юзом начинал сползать вниз под крутой уклон…» [В.А. Солоухин. Владимирские просёлки (1956-1957)]

«…это было раздражение, что писатели, видевшие большую мрачную эпоху, всё стараются юзом проскользнуть, не сказать нам ничего главного…» [А.И. Солженицын]

Понятие «двигаться юзом» означает: скользить (соскальзывать), или ползти (сползать) или тащить волоком (не катом). 
Понятия лезет, ползёт, скользит вполне соответствуют движениям ужа (гада). 
Сани (лыжи) всегда скользят. Колесные повозки идут «катом» или «юзом» (скользя), а порой -медленно «ползут». Логично, что термины, характеризующие способы перемещения живых тварей, стали использоваться в технике.

Очень похоже, что наречия «юзом» и «ужом» - это разные формы одного слова, а существительное «юз» образовано от (соответствующего по звучанию) наречия.

Comment: Идея о связи с ужом - Ваша?

Comment: Идея принадлежит А И. Солженицину. Так мне кажется.